# How do I do a v look up between two different spread sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This column has 3 responses , accept , decline or did not respond. I Need to do a v look up between two different spreadsheets of different days  that gives the output of  people that did not respond to the email in spreadsheet 1 , who have now  responded the following day in either accepting or declining in the spreadsheet 2, how would I do a v look up to find this ?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: VLOOKUP() or maybe index() with match() could work but without any example data (which you should provide in a text format not as an image) it is difficult to suggest more.

Comment: I would suggest XLOOKUP over VLOOKUP... it's pretty straightforward, start typing =XLOOKUP into the formula bar and follow the prompts... `=XLOOKUP (person, people, response, "not_found", 0)`   It would be helpful if you could add more information or a screenshot.